# Stop Gradle from building

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio to build my project. 
I click Run(Shift + F10) in Android Studio, a Gradle build is started
[image]

How do I disable Gradle from doing this each time I run?

Comment: When you run your app you need gradle to build in order to generate apk, why you want to stop it?

Comment: for run your app it's necessary

Comment: #Tài.Nguyễn Do't do this

Comment: @cwfei It  is pretty slow.  It is take a long time when run project

Comment: yes but if you stop it you are unable to run the project, consider getting a SSD

Answer (score 4):

The build process involves many tools and processes that generate intermediate files on the way to producing an .apk. If you are developing in Android Studio, the complete build process is done every time you run the Gradle build task for your project or modules. The build process is very flexible so it's useful, however, to understand what is happening under the hood since much of the build process is configurable and extensible.

> Gradle applies industry proven conventions and coins several new ones
>   to enable you to kickstart your build with minimal effort.

So , **Don't** try This .

> [What is Gradle in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Android is not like it was before when eclipse was main tool for android, have separated a build process from IDE. 
Now the IDE is InteliJ which you using and for build process you useing gradle.

- IDE is just editor. (InteliJ)
- Gradle is just a build tool.
- IDE use build tool to build the project, because IDE itself can not do it.

i.e You should NOT stop gradle process in InteliJ.

Comment: But I built project more time. It is take a long time when run project

Comment: compiling take some time

Answer (score 1):

Gradle **needs** to build each time you run the project. It compiles all of your dependencies and as the comment states generates your .apk file.

The best that you can do is [speed up](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/) the process considerably.

Here is why you need Gradle, if you are unfamiliar with this: [Purpose of Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787986/what-is-the-purpose-of-gradle).

Answer (score 0):

Gradle runs every time when you start or run your project. It is a build system that builds your app and compiles all the stuff in one place.

So if you stop building with Gradle your app does not start.

You have to build it. It is compulsory.